# htaccess redirect - if URL has date format modify the URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect (using htaccess),

`https://www.example.com/2023/06/16`

To

`https://www.example.com/news/2023/06/16`

**There are thousands of URLs** because 2023 could be changed with any past year and 06 with any month and 16 with any day, but luckily all are numbers with "/" separators.

Have to do this very carefully, even checking if there are two "/" in the URL after a year, because otherwise other similar URLs may be jammed.

**I wrote a htaccess code and it's working fine, but please let me know if anything is wrong in this code.**

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /news/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is unnecessarily complex. Just use a simple `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})/?$ /news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This also fixes two issue sin your implementation: potentially trailing stuff in the requested URL and your redirection target which would only cite the year, but not month and day.

That implementation will work likewise, in the central http server's host configuration (the preferred place to implement such rules) or also a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), if that feature has been enabled and the file is located in the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Not sure why you added a question mark to the redirection target in your implementation. If that was meant to get rid of a potential query string then use the `QSD` flag instead.